# Find the origin of subview with respect to UIImage size

Tags: ios, uiimage, frame

**This is the hierarchy:**

```
-- ViewController.View P [width: 375, height: 667]
---- UIImageView A       [width: 375, height: 667]
                         [A is holding an image of size(1287,1662)]
---- UIImageView B       [width: 100, height: 100]
                         [B is holding an image of size(2400,982)]
```

> Note: B is not a subview of A. In the app, B is draggable. And I am trying to merge two A and B where positions are, A [background] and B [foreground].

I want to find the exact position of B such that, after merging it will be at the same position where I dragged & dropped.

1. I have written all the code for drag and drop.
2. I couldn't find a proper position of B for merging with A.

Here are the problem screenshots:

---

**Showing the initial position of B.**

[image: Showing the initial position of B.]

---

**This is the new position of B after drag and drop.**

[image: This is the new position of B.]

---

**Wrong position of B after merging.**

[image: Wrong position of B after merging.]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Attention**! : Attached images Sample Later and a Signature inside the screenshots has been founded in Google search. I have used for demonstration purpose only.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried already, what results you are getting and some code.

Comment: @Scriptable, thanks. Question updated with screenshots. It may be helpful. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Because the images are larger than the actual display they are being scaled. you'll need to calculate the scale factor for each to calculate relative position. I'll try and do some sample code shorlty to see how to do it. Could you provide a source image for one of the letters and signatures. or something of similar size

Answer (score 0):

Because the imageView's size is different from the original image ,instead of merging two images via two view's ABSOLUTE position , you can use a RELATIVE position.

Sudo-code :

```
let relativeOrigin = {(B's origin.x in A) / A.width , (B's origin.y in A) / A.height}
let actualOrigin = { imgAWidth * relativeOrigin.x , imgAHeight * relativeOrigin.y } //this should be the correct absolute origin.
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't help as it's still given me the wrong position for the B.

Answer (score 0):

**You can consider it as a suggestion:**

```
FullscreenPoint.frame.origin.y = (screenShot.frame.origin.y*FullImage.frame.size.height)/screenShot.frame.size.height;                        
FullscreenPoint.frame.origin.x = (screenShot.frame.origin.x*FullImage.frame.size.width)/screenShot.frame.size.width;
```

Comment: This doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use imageView's (A) frame.size instead of A.image.size to get the right location while merging.

Here's the code:

```
func mixImagesWith(frontImage:UIImage?, backgroundImage: UIImage?, atPoint point:CGPoint, ofSize signatureSize:CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let size = self.imgBackground.frame.size
    //let size = self.imgBackground.image!.size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    backgroundImage?.draw(in: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    frontImage?.draw(in: CGRect.init(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: signatureSize.width, height: signatureSize.height))
    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```