# How to merge two UIImages while keeping their position, size and aspect ratios?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

**I am trying to merge two `UIImage`s of different sizes.**

I have `UIImage A` is of the following size: `1287 × 1662` pixels
And `UIImage B` is of the following size: `200 × 200` pixels

---

I am showing A and B in following `UIImageView`s.

`UIImageView` **backgroundImageView** of the size: `375 x 667`
And `UIImageView` **foregroundImageView** of the size: `100 x 100`

User can move `foregroundImageView` to any position above the `backgroundImageView`.

---

**This is the merging code:**

```
let previewImage:UIImage? = mergeImages(img: imgBackground.image!, sizeWaterMark: CGRect.init(origin: imgForeground.frame.origin, size: CGSize.init(width: 100, height: 100)), waterMarkImage: imgForeground.image!)

func mergeImages(img:UIImage, sizeWaterMark:CGRect, waterMarkImage:UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let size = self.imgBackground.frame.size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    img.draw(in: getAspectFitFrame(sizeImgView: size, sizeImage: img.size))
    let frameAspect:CGRect = getAspectFitFrame(sizeImgView: sizeWaterMark.size, sizeImage: waterMarkImage.size)
    let frameOrig:CGRect = CGRect(x: sizeWaterMark.origin.x+frameAspect.origin.x, y: sizeWaterMark.origin.y+frameAspect.origin.y, width: frameAspect.size.width, height: frameAspect.size.height)
    waterMarkImage.draw(in: frameOrig, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)
    let result:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return result
}

func getAspectFitFrame(sizeImgView:CGSize, sizeImage:CGSize) -> CGRect {

    let imageSize:CGSize  = sizeImage
    let viewSize:CGSize = sizeImgView

    let hfactor : CGFloat = imageSize.width/viewSize.width
    let vfactor : CGFloat = imageSize.height/viewSize.height

    let factor : CGFloat = max(hfactor, vfactor)

    // Divide the size by the greater of the vertical or horizontal shrinkage factor
    let newWidth : CGFloat = imageSize.width / factor
    let newHeight : CGFloat = imageSize.height / factor

    var x:CGFloat = 0.0
    var y:CGFloat = 0.0

    if hfactor > vfactor {
        y = (sizeImgView.height - newHeight) / 2
    } else {
        x = (sizeImgView.width - newWidth) / 2
    }
    let newRect:CGRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
    return newRect
}
```

This is actually merging and giving me what I am looking for. But it's reducing the size of merged image. As you can see this line in the `mergeImages` function.

```
    let size = self.imgBackground.frame.size
```

I want the size should be the original `UIImage A` size. So if I change it to this,

```
    let size = self.imgBackground.image!.size
```

This will change the location of the B over A, after merging.

For testing, you can download and check the source code from [here](https://github.com/hemangshah/MergeImages).

**What should I do to keep the original size as it is while having the exact position of B over A with proper aspect ratio?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made utility functions static (it's even better to move them in separate file) to be sure that they are not using `ViewController` instance properties and methods.

In `mergeImages` I removed:

```
let size = self.imgBackground.frame.size
```

and replaced `size` with `img.size`. It's the same as using `self.imgBackground.image!.size` as you described in question.

Because source and target image sizes are the same there is no need to adjust aspect and we simply replace:

```
img.draw(in: getAspectFitFrame(sizeImgView: size, sizeImage: img.size))
```

with

```
img.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: img.size))
```

Also I extracted aspect factor calculation to separate function `getFactor` to make code more granular and made `getAspectFitFrame` return not only `CGRect` but also aspect factor (it'll be useful later).

So utility functions are now looking like:

```
static func mergeImages(img: UIImage, sizeWaterMark: CGRect, waterMarkImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    img.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: img.size))
    let (frameAspect, _) = getAspectFitFrame(from: sizeWaterMark.size, to: waterMarkImage.size)
    let frameOrig = CGRect(x: sizeWaterMark.origin.x + frameAspect.origin.x, y: sizeWaterMark.origin.y + frameAspect.origin.y, width: frameAspect.size.width, height: frameAspect.size.height)
    waterMarkImage.draw(in: frameOrig, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)
    let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return result
}

static func getAspectFitFrame(from: CGSize, to: CGSize) -> (CGRect, CGFloat) {
    let (hfactor, vfactor, factor) = ViewController.getFactor(from: from, to: to)

    // Divide the size by the greater of the vertical or horizontal shrinkage factor
    let newWidth = to.width / factor
    let newHeight = to.height / factor

    var x: CGFloat = 0.0
    var y: CGFloat = 0.0

    if hfactor > vfactor {
        y = (from.height - newHeight) / 2
    } else {
        x = (from.width - newWidth) / 2
    }
    return (CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: newWidth, height: newHeight), factor)
}

static func getFactor(from: CGSize, to: CGSize) -> (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) {
    let hfactor = to.width / from.width
    let vfactor = to.height / from.height
    return (hfactor, vfactor, max(hfactor, vfactor))
}
```

Also you need another utility function to calculate scaled water mark origin and size:

```
static func getScaledFrame(from: CGSize, to: CGSize, target: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let (aspectFitFrame, factor) = ViewController.getAspectFitFrame(from: from, to: to)
    return CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(
                    x: (target.origin.x - aspectFitFrame.origin.x) * factor,
                    y: (target.origin.y - aspectFitFrame.origin.y) * factor),
            size: CGSize(width: target.width * factor, height: target.height * factor)
    )
}
```

Now you are ready to render merged image:

```
    let previewImage = ViewController.mergeImages(
            img: imgBackground.image!,
            sizeWaterMark: ViewController.getScaledFrame(from: imgBackground.frame.size, to: imgBackground.image!.size, target: imgForeground.frame),
            waterMarkImage: imgForeground.image!
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps me a lot. :)